# How to print the cursor values in oracle?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g, sys-refcursor

I am new to oracle and I am learning cursors.My table City has two columns city_id,city_name.So,this is what I tried:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR city_list is
  SELECT * from OT.City;

  v_list SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN city_list FOR
   v_list := city_list;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_list.city_id);
   EXIT WHEN city_list%NOTFOUND;
  CLOSE city_list;
END;
/
```

i am trying to assign the data of cursor to the newly declared value   `v_list SYS_REFCURSOR;`.But the output is coming as error at `v_list := city_list;`.How can I assign all the values of cursors to the another cursor directly or is there any other methods?

Comment: On a side note: It's far easier to work with implicit cursors, e.g.: `for rec in (select * from ot.city) loop dbms_output.put_line(rec.city_id); end loop;`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can still use `SYS_REFCURSOR` by locating between `OPEN` and `FOR` clauses, and followed by your cursor, and then

need to add `LOOP FETCH INTO... END LOOP` template and Close the opened cursor after you current code :

```
DECLARE
  v_list SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_city_id   city.city_id%TYPE;
  v_city_name city.city_name%TYPE;
BEGIN 
  OPEN v_list FOR
    SELECT city_id, city_name FROM City;

  LOOP 
    FETCH v_list
    INTO  v_city_id, v_city_name;
    EXIT WHEN v_list%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_city_id || ' - ' || v_city_name);
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE v_list;  
END;
/
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a6e8f2e05b051bccf23a6eb53203e9a4)</kbd>

Answer (score 7):

This question is tagged with oracle 11g, but let me provide the new way to return result which is introduced in oracle 12c.

`DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(l_cursor)` can be used to print the result in oracle 12c.

```
DECLARE
 v_list SYS_REFCURSOR
BEGIN
 Open v_list for
 SELECT * from OT.City;

 DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_list);
END;
/
```

Cheers!!

Comment: but what for 11g?

Comment: @Tejash, is `DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT` is the only alternative for DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE inside loop to print the cursor result? or this can be used anywhere else also?

Comment: As far as I know, This is the only alternative. others are to write in the file.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your code, for example:

- `v_list` should be declared as  `city_list%ROWTYPE`
- you need to `OPEN` the cursor and then `LOOP`
- to assign the current record to `city_list`, you want to use `FETCH INTO`

Consider this new version of your code:

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR city_list IS SELECT * from city ORDER BY city_id;
    v_list city_list%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    OPEN city_list;
    LOOP
        FETCH city_list INTO v_list;
        EXIT when city_list%notfound;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_list.city_id);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE city_list;

END;
/
```

In **[this demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cd07cb8a37126f67809a8f792b37f1e5)**, given the following content for the `city` table:

```
CITY_ID | CITY_NAME  
------: | :----------
      1 | New York   
      2 | Los Angeles
```

The code outputs:

```
1 rows affected

dbms_output:
1
2
```

Answer (score 2):

In 11g the simplest way to print values from the cursor is to pass the cursor variable:

```
var rc refcursor
begin
    open :rc for
    select City.* from (
        select rownum id, trim (column_value) name 
        from xmlTable ('"New York","Paris"')) City;
end;
/
print rc

        ID NAME            
---------- ----------------
         1 New York        
         2 Paris
```

Comment: ``set autoprint on`` or use ``print rc;`` after the PL/SQL block.